# How can modify this select statement

Tags: sql, select

how can I modify below union select statement to any join select statement method, its to sum price from table 1 and table 2, I'm trying as well,

```
select CODE, SUM(PRICE) as PRICE 
from (SELECT CODE, SUM(PRICE) as PRICE 
       FROM TABLE1 
       where ID='IBK' and cast(TMSTAMP_UPDATE as DATE)='2014-03-31' 
       GROUP BY CODE 
      union 
      SELECT CODE, SUM(PRICE) as PRICE 
       FROM TABLE2 
       where ID='IBK' and cast(TMSTAMP_UPDATE as DATE)='2014-03-31' 
       GROUP BY CODE) GROUP BY CODE;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  Can you try rephrasing it?

Comment: Can you explain why a join would be an issue here, also is there a business purpose for changing it from a join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
select CODE, SUM(PRICE) as PRICE 
from (SELECT CODE, SUM(PRICE) as PRICE 
       FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON
      t1.ID=t2.ID and 
      t1. cast(TMSTAMP_UPDATE as DATE)='2014-03-31' 
      = t2.cast(TMSTAMP_UPDATE as DATE)='2014-03-31' and
      t1.ID='IBK' and t1.cast(TMSTAMP_UPDATE as DATE)='2014-03-31'  
GROUP BY CODE) GROUP BY CODE;
```